# tar error on debian linux

Tags: linux, debian

I downloaded a firefox tarball. When I try to extract `Firefox-latest.tar.bz2` by:

```
sudo tar -jxvf Firefox-latest.tar.bz2
```

some errors appear on the terminal:

```
tar: .: Not found in archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

then I try to command:

```
sudo tar -jxf Firefox-latest.tar.bz2
```

still error!

so, I how do I solve this error ?  and why does it happen?

Comment: and without sudo? Does it work?

Comment: when I use root acount without sudo , but still error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the download was incomplete, the error should have been something like

```
$ tar jxvf firefox-12.0.tar.bz2
firefox/
firefox/mozilla-xremote-client
firefox/platform.ini
firefox/libsoftokn3.chk
firefox/libnssckbi.so
firefox/libxul.so

bzip2: Compressed file ends unexpectedly;
    perhaps it is corrupted?  *Possible* reason follows.
bzip2: Inappropriate ioctl for device
    Input file = (stdin), output file = (stdout)

It is possible that the compressed file(s) have become corrupted.
You can use the -tvv option to test integrity of such files.

You can use the `bzip2recover' program to attempt to recover
data from undamaged sections of corrupted files.

tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Unexpected EOF in archive
tar: Error is not recoverable: exiting now
```

**However**, the output you describe is exactly what one gets if one executes:

```
$ tar jxvf firefox-12.0.tar.bz2 .
tar: .: Not found in archive
tar: Exiting with failure status due to previous errors
```

I believe you had a trailing `.` for some reason. Perhaps since you thought you had to specify extraction directory in that way (you *can* specify it with `-C` if you want, but `.` is the default).

Comment: the question has been solved , and you are right, I shouldn't specify extraction directory in that way , your way is right, thank you !

Comment: @YoungkingWang: If this answer solved the question, you should mark it as correct by clicking the check mark next to it. This site relies on questions being marked as "answered" when they are resolved.

Answer (score 2):

Try re-downloading the file. `tar -jxvf firefox-12.0.tar.bz2` worked on my system after downloading it from here: http://www.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/all.html

Answer (score 0):

was the download of the file complete without errors and the correct size?  if you run "file Firefox-latest.tar.bz2" , what is returned?

Comment: the file Firefox is complete without errors because I can extract this   file by using the gnome extract tool ,but I can't extract it on terminal, so how should i do